Which part of the Bible supposedly prophesies a time when everything would be lush but man wouldn't be able to use any of it?
In Chernobyl Prayer (or Voices from Chernobyl), one of the persons interviewed by Svetlana Alexievich says,

Many years ago, my grandfather read in the Bible that there would come a time on earth when everything would be lush, everything would blossom and bear fruit, the rivers would be teeming with fish, the forests full of animals, but man wouldn't be able to use any of it. And we wouldn't be able to produce our own kind, prolong our immortality. I listened to those old prophecies like they were scary tales.

(Chernobyl Prayer, translated by Anna Gunin and Arch Tait. Penguin, 2016. Page 95.)
I have not been able to identify a Bible passage with this kind of prophecy. The list What Does the Bible Say About Taking Care Of The Earth? on OpenBible.info doesn't contain anything that matches well with the description above.
Below are a few passages in more detail (each time quoted from the English Standard Version or ESV).
Jeremiah 2:7:

And I brought you into a plentiful land
to enjoy its fruits and its good things.
But when you came in, you defiled my land
and made my heritage an abomination.

This isn't a prophecy, and several other elements, such as the fish in the rivers and the animals in the forests, are missing, both from this verse and its context.
Leviticus 19: passim:

“When you offer a sacrifice of peace offerings to the Lord, you shall offer it so that you may be accepted.
6 It shall be eaten the same day you offer it or on the day after, and anything left over until the third day shall be burned up with fire.
7 If it is eaten at all on the third day, it is tainted; it will not be accepted,
8 and everyone who eats it shall bear his iniquity, because he has profaned what is holy to the Lord, and that person shall be cut off from his people.
9 “When you reap the harvest of your land, you shall not reap your field right up to its edge, neither shall you gather the gleanings after your harvest.
10 And you shall not strip your vineyard bare, neither shall you gather the fallen grapes of your vineyard. You shall leave them for the poor and for the sojourner: I am the Lord your God.
(…)
23 “When you come into the land and plant any kind of tree for food, then you shall regard its fruit as forbidden. Three years it shall be forbidden to you; it must not be eaten.
24 And in the fourth year all its fruit shall be holy, an offering of praise to the Lord.   25 But in the fifth year you may eat of its fruit, to increase its yield for you: I am the Lord your God.

This is not a prophecy but a series of commandments, or rather prohibitions.
Ezekiel 47: 7–12:

7 As I went back, I saw on the bank of the river very many trees on the one side and on the other.
8 And he said to me, “This water flows toward the eastern region and goes down into the Arabah, and enters the sea; when the water flows into the sea, the water will become fresh.
9 And wherever the river goes, every living creature that swarms will live, and there will be very many fish. For this water goes there, that the waters of the sea may become fresh; so everything will live where the river goes.
10 Fishermen will stand beside the sea. From Engedi to Eneglaim it will be a place for the spreading of nets. Its fish will be of very many kinds, like the fish of the Great Sea.
11 But its swamps and marshes will not become fresh; they are to be left for salt.
12 And on the banks, on both sides of the river, there will grow all kinds of trees for food. Their leaves will not wither, nor their fruit fail, but they will bear fresh fruit every month, because the water for them flows from the sanctuary. Their fruit will be for food, and their leaves for healing.”

This is a prophecy, but the passage does not say anything about animals in the forests, not about man not being able to use any of it.
Revelation 22: 1–5:

Then the angel showed me the river of the water of life, bright as crystal, flowing from the throne of God and of the Lamb
2 through the middle of the street of the city; also, on either side of the river, the tree of life with its twelve kinds of fruit, yielding its fruit each month. The leaves of the tree were for the healing of the nations.
3 No longer will there be anything accursed, but the throne of God and of the Lamb will be in it, and his servants will worship him.
4 They will see his face, and his name will be on their foreheads.
5 And night will be no more. They will need no light of lamp or sun, for the Lord God will be their light, and they will reign forever and ever.

This is part of a prophecy but several elements, such as the fish in the rivers and the animals in the forests, are missing. There is no claim that man would not be use any of the fruit.
So what passage of the Bible was the interviewee's grandfather reading?

As far as I can remember, there is nothing like this in the Bible. Like many Biblical “quotes”¹ this is more likely a case of something misremembered and distorted.


A notable example of this would be the lion lying down with the lamb (which is a distortion of a couple passages in Isaiah where it’s actually a wolf dwelling or grazing with the lamb while the lion lies down with a young calf and fatling or eats straw like an ox).


But is it misremembered on the part of the character, or on the part of the author? (Or is there any way to tell?)

Voices from Chernobyl, being a collection of interviews, won’t have characters per se, so the question is whether the grandfather or the interview subject misremembered and there’s really no way to say, although I interpreted it as the grandfather and assumed the interviewee was a reliable narrator, but it could be the other way around too with them adding details to the recollection informed by the experience of Chernobyl.
